# Open Chrome with only the pinned tabs

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, pinning, application-launch

Previously, when you have some pinned tabs, Chrome opens only those on startup.

But when I launch Chrome, the pinned tabs **and** my regular home page tab is opened. How do I set up Chrome so that only the pinned tabs are opened, without any regular tabs?

[image]

Based on the picture above, I only want the 3 pinned tabs to open on launch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Go to **Options** > **Basics** > **On Startup**

Select **Open the following pages**, but leave the field blank.

[image]

It works on my laptop: Windows 7, Chrome 13.0.782.215.

Comment: No longer works.